# Cannot find symbol class MakeText error

Tags: java, android, toast

Here's how I implement Toast:

```
    if ((name == "") || (pass == "")){
        Toast invalidLoginToast = new Toast.makeText(this, "aaa", 3).show();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, AnnouncementsActivity.class);
        String deviceId = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        intent.putExtra("NAME", name);
        intent.putExtra("ID", deviceId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

But I get the error

> Error:(34, 48) error: cannot find symbol class makeText

Neccessary imports are already made. Am I sending wrong parameters into the method?

Comment: see also [comapre strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: define toast like `Toast invalidLoginToast =  Toast.makeText(this, "aaa", 3).show();` and remove `new` keyword

Comment: It's recommended to use "".equals(str) to avoid NullPointerException

Answer (score 3):

> Instantiate a Toast object with one of the makeText() methods. This
>   method takes three parameters: the application Context, the text
>   message, and the duration for the toast. It returns a properly
>   initialized Toast object. You can display the toast notification with
>   show();

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration)
```

Read official guideline about **[Toast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html)**  .

```
  Toast.makeText(CurrentActivityName.this,"aaa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `Toast.makeText(this, "aaa", LENGHT_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong,

```
Toast invalidLoginToast = new Toast.makeText(this, "aaa", 3).show();
```

Replace it with

```
Toast.makeText(this, "aaa", 3).show();
```

Toast is having `makeText` method as static, and you can call it from the class name, don't call it the way you are calling it(i.e by new operator).
For further info, please visit the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
```

context

> getApplicationContext() - Returns the context for all activities
>   running in application.
>
> getBaseContext() - If you want to access Context from another context
>   within application you can access.
>
> getContext() - Returns the context view only current running activity.

text

> text - Return "STRING" , If not string you can use type cast. 
>   (string)num   // type caste duration

duration

> Toast.LENGTH_SHORT - Toast delay 2000 ms predefined
>
> Toast.LENGTH_LONG - Toast delay 3500 ms predefined
>
> milisecond - Toast delay user defined miliseconds (eg. 4000)

```
if ((name.equals("")) || (pass.equals(""))){
     Toast.makeText(this,"aaa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,).show();
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to use "".equals(str) to avoid NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast invalidLoginToast = new Toast.makeText(this, "aaa", 3).show();
```

just remove the part `(Toast invalidLoginToast = new)` from your coding as you don't need to create object to Toast class to access makeText function, because its static it can be accessed directly using class name itself as `Toast.makeText`

just write it as

```
Toast.makeText(this, "aaa", 3).show();
```

(or)

```
Toast.makeText(this,"aaa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove new keyword in front of Toast initialization.
use

```
Toast invalidLoginToast = Toast.makeText(this, "aaa", 3).show();
```

You don't need to use `new` keyword while creating Toast as it is provided by factory method inside Toast which does that for you.

> Instantiate a Toast object with one of the makeText() methods. This
>   method takes three parameters: the application Context, the text
>   message, and the duration for the toast. It returns a properly
>   initialized Toast object. You can display the toast notification with
>   show()